# Page Redirect to selected contact

Tags: apex, contact, redirect

I have a VF Page where Im displaying a lost of contacts as a link. I need to redirect the command link (Name of contact) to that particular contact's standard detail page. Please help me with a sample code.

My Page

```
<apex:pageBlock >
            <table>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Conlst}" var="C" style="font-size: 15px;">
<td style="width:30%">
            <apex:column headerValue="Clients" style="background-color:#F7EADD;color :white;font-family: Times New Roman">
 <apex:commandLink action="{!ViewData}">{!C.Name}</apex:commandLink>
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!ShowTransactions}"/> 
            </apex:column>
            </td>             
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

My Controller

```
public class Transactionrecordnew { 
public Boolean displayBlock{ get; set; }

public string ClientId{get;set;}
Public String selectedName {get;set;}
public string ProductId{get;set;}    
public List<Contact> lstContact {get; set;}

  public Transactionrecordnew()
   {
      getTransaction();
      displayBlock = false;
      Conlst = [select Id,Name, Group__c  from Contact where Group__c='Client'];
      assets=null;
       }

 public PageReference ViewData() {
 pagereference ref =new pagereference('/' + contactId);
  ref.setredirect(true);
  return ref;
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid a use of controller method for redirection. Just use a normal HTML `a` tag for that! It will save some resources.

```
<a href="/{!C.Id}">{!C.Name}</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

No need of action attribute(I assume).Replace it with "value" attribute.So when u select a contact it automatically redirects to the detail page.

Page looks like:

```
<apex:pageBlock >
            <table>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Conlst}" var="C" style="font-size: 15px;">
<td style="width:30%">
            <apex:column headerValue="Clients" style="background-color:#F7EADD;color :white;font-family: Times New Roman">
 <apex:commandLink value="/{!C.id}"**>{!C.Name}</apex:commandLink>
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!ShowTransactions}"/> 
            </apex:column>
            </td>             
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```